# Sub Domain implementation In MVC 5 Application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, azure, model-view-controller

We are developing a MVC 5 application. Suppose the main site is like www.sport.com

Now we want to create **3 sub domain like cricket.sport.com, football.sport.com and hockey.sport.com**

Most of the functionality will be same for this 3 sub-sites.

We have implemented 2 approaches :

Approach 1: Create 3 area for each cricket/football/hockey. But this will create code redundancy. So **whenever request comes from URL we check and forward request to specific area.**

Approach 2 : Create Single Controller - **Check URL SubDomain and redirect depending upon each request and display specific view**. In this approach, each time we need to check request sub domain and forward to same.

**What is best possible way to implement sub domain in MVC application?**

We want to deploy this site on Windows Azure.

Answer (score 0):

What you mean by `implement sub domain` isn't all too clear.

If you are trying to host the same sight at different sub domains and expect them to work differently then you should have something in your `web.config` or some other setting that then tell each site what it is.

Something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>        
    <appSettings>
      <add key="AppType" value="criket" />
    </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Then inside your application you'll do:

```
if(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["AppType"] == "cricket")
{
   //do cricket app specific stuff 
} else { /* do something else */ }
```

If this whole thing doesn't need to be dynamic you could also have a build symbol :

```
//uncomment or comment accordingly
#define CRIKET 
//#define FOOTBALL 

    public class HomeController
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
#if CRICKET
            return View("Cricket");
#elif FOOTBALL
            return View("Football");
#endif
        }
    }
```

A config setting is slower than a build symbol but it gives you a dynamic approach. Choose according to your need.

Comment: Thank you. But Sub Domain means I am thinking that when URL like Cricket.Sport.com it only display cricket related details. this may different in 3 , i.e. football, cricket, hockey.

Comment: Nope, I think you're on the wrong page. A sub-domain is usually used to host a **subsite**, which is **a whole new site**. A good example is http://stackexchange.com there is http://math.stackexchange.com http://biologystackexchange.com etc they're the **same engine** but they're different sites, each with their own UI. They're configured accordingly. And by configured I mean what I mentioned in my answer.